# problema con jre y jdk en eclipse para conectar con mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Buenos días, estoy tratando de conectar una base de datos con mi codigo pero a la hora de ejecutar sale la siguiente excepción:

> "the JAR fie C:\Program Files\Java\Jre1.8.0_151\ext\mysql-connector-java-8.07-dmr-bin.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below".

Ya lo he intentando con otros **.jar de mysql** y ni así, de antemano les agradezco sus aportes para la solución del problema.

```
package prode;
import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {

Connection con;
Statement st;

public Conexion(){
    try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // en el debug llega a esta parte mostrando por class file editor la excepción; en ejecución no lanza errores, llega al catch mostrando conexión no establecida
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prodemios?user=root&password=");

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e){
        System.out.println("conexion no establecida");
    }
}

}
```

Me brindaron la solucion de cambiar el jre a jdk, pero al hacerlo me lanza lo siguiente Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.io.FileInputStream.available()I
    at java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.inReady(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.MetaIndex.registerDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(Unknown Source)

En verdad estoy trabajando de forma empirica y no estoy seguro si hice bien en cambiar jre 151 a jdk 161 o 162 que fue con los que hice los cambios en los JREs instalados, busqué un jdk 151 como para saber si era por eso el error pero no lo encuentro, por favor les pido su ayuda frente a este tema, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor no dupliques las preguntas. Esto mismo venias preguntando ayer. la forma de hacer una pregunta mas visible es agregando la informacion a la misma. Explica bien los pasos que hiciste en la otra pregunta y muestra el codigo que falla.

Comment: creí que aquí habían expertos, no es un problema de código, y si lo pregunto de nuevo es por que la pregunta anterior era con otro tipo de excepción si te fijas, solo que la solución brindada me sirvió pero lanzó otra excepción por consiguiente lanzo otra pregunta ya que no recibo inmediatez, muchas gracias por tu aporte igual

Comment: "pero a la hora de ejecutar".. entonces que estas ejecutando? tenes que ser mas claro, si no no se sabe de que estas hablando concretamente

Comment: en ejecución llega al catch informando por consola que la conexión no se estableció, sin mostrar errores, pero en el debug muestra esa excepción en el class file editor, al llegar al Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Eso no es un error. Eso quiere decir que el IDE que estas usando no tiene el codigo fuente que "necesitarias" para hacer un debug. No es un error de la libreria. Por eso te digo, tu problema puede estar en el codigo, en la cadena de conexion a la base de datos, o en otro lado.

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta con el codigo y me dices, solo he generado el código de conexión, permiteme.

Comment: Perfecto.. ahora si en lugar de mostrar esa cadena, te fijas que tiene el objeto e para ver cual es el error real?

Comment: En lugar de ese System.out... prueba a poner un `e.printStackTrace()` y averigua qué falla al intentar hacer la conexión, será más útil que intentar depurar el código del driver de MySQL

Answer (score 0):

La forma para arreglar el error sería cambiar de usar `jre` a usar `jdk` dentro de Eclipse.

Dentro de eclipse vaya a menú `Windows-> Preferencias-> Java-> JRE instalados`.

Seleccione Examinar y navegue hasta el directorio `C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`.

Eclipse buscará automáticamente la fuente y la asociará con las clases de JDK.

Si aún desea usar jre en eclipse, entra al menú `Windows-> Preferences-> JRE instaladas en Java`.

Seleccione la `jre` que está usando. Haga clic en Editar. En el cuadro de diálogo resultante, seleccione todos los archivos `jar`.

Haga clic en el botón Adjunto de origen. Navegue al archivo `src.zip` al que hizo referencia en su mensaje y selecciónelo.